# How to replace image pixel in Webos Palm js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, webos, palm-pre

I want to replace image pixel color with other color in webos. so can any one suggest how i do this. 
Thanks

Comment: you'll probably have more success doing image processing with the PDK

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the HTML5 canvas API. Create a canvas the size of the image, and then draw the image into the canvas. Get the image data, and manipulate away!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

`image` is now an `imageData` object, which contains an array `data`, which contains all pixels of the image.
Suppose you wanted to remove the green component at the pixel in the sixth column and the third row.

```
var index = (5*image.width+2)*4;
//six columns of pixels, plus two for the third row.
//Multiply by four, because there are four channels.
image.data[index+1] = 0; //Plus one, because we want the second component.
```

Once your pixel manipulation is done, load the image data back into the canvas.

```
context.putImageData(image);
```